# GAPI is not defined - Svelte3

Tags: javascript, svelte, google-api-js-client, svelte-3

I'm having an issue when trying to implement the Youtube data API in my Svelte app. Whenever the site is loaded it just spits the following error:
`Uncaught ReferenceError: gapi is not defined`

The relevant code currently looks as follows:

```js
<svelte:head>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
    
</svelte:head>
<script>
    
function start() {
  console.log(GAPIKEY);
  // 2. Initialize the JavaScript client library.
  gapi.client.init({
    'apiKey': GAPIKEY,
  }).then(function() {
    // 3. Initialize and make the API request.
    return gapi.client.request({
      'path': 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists',
      'id': 'PLy3-VH7qrUZ5IVq_lISnoccVIYZCMvi-8'
    })
  }).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response.result);
  }, function(reason) {
    console.log('Error: ' + reason.result.error.message);
  });
};

gapi.load('client', start);
</script>
```

From what I'm able to tell from other similiar Stackoverflow posts this seems to be related to using `async` and `defer` in script tags, causing gapi to not be loaded before the code is ran.  However since I'm using Svelte, who seems to auto-add them to the compiled code, I am unsure how I am supposed to solve this?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>` to your `index.html` on the public folder instead of loading it on the `<svelte:head>`

Comment: This seems to have worked, thanks a ton! Got a new error message now but it was from the google api, so im assuming it's separate. Anyway, thanks a lot for the help again :)!